# Appending just one column of a dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, join, pyspark, left-join

```
df_1 =

metadata_id     col_1     col_2      col_3
        100         1         2          3
        101         1         2          1
        102         2         5          3
        103         1         2          6
        104         1         4          2
        105         6         2          3


df_2 =

      my_metadata_id       col_4      col_5     version
                 100           1          2          10
                 101           1          7          11
                 201           2          2          11
                 102           1          2          12
                 202           1          2          12
                 302           6          5          12
                 103           1          2          13
                 104           2          1          14
                 105           1          2          15
```

Desired output:

```
metadata_id     col_1     col_2      col_3     version
        100         1         2          3          10
        101         1         2          1          11
        102         2         5          3          12
        103         1         2          6          13
        104         1         4          2          14
        105         6         2          3          15
```

It looks trivial, but when I do:

```
df_1 = df_1.join(df_2.select("version"), df_1("metadata_id") == df_2("my_metadata_id"), how="left")
```

I get: `TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable`.

I would just join normally and then drop the extra columns, but in reality there is a lot of them and I wouldn't do it manually when there must be an elegant solution...

Comment: you should be using square brackets when providing column names. e.g. in `df_1["metadata_id"]`. also, be sure to select the key fields as well

Comment: @samkart What do you mean by selecting key fields?

Comment: join keys -- `my_metadata_id`

Comment: @samkart so: `df_1 = df_1.join(df_2.select("version", "my_metadata_id"), df_1["metadata_id"] == df_2["my_metadata_id"], how="left")`  ?

Comment: yes, should resolve the error

Comment: @johnnydoe - `df_1.join(df_2.select('version', 'my_metadata_id'), df_1["metadata_id"] == df_2["my_metadata_id"], "left").drop('my_metadata_id')` does the trick.